# UITableView cell shows same images on fast scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am creating the iPhone app which shows the app icons & app names in table view.

First time i download the images in user document directory & then make entry in dictionary [value - image stored document directory path & key is image json URL], for showing image in cell first i checked the image is already download or not.

If downloaded, then show the local image which stored on document directory and if not download it.

If i Scrolled normally, cell shows the rights images & if i scrolled it fast, cell shows the same images instead of different.

```
// code for displaying images

-(void)refreshViews
{

self.appLabelName.text = _applicationObject.name;
self.appLabelName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17];
self.detailTextLabel.text = _applicationObject.artistName;
self.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];


NSString *appIconStoredPath = [appDelgate.saveAppIconURLAndPathInFile valueForKey:_applicationObject.iconURL];
_appIcon.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:appIconStoredPath];

if(!_appIcon.image && appDelgate.hasInternetConnection)
{
    [self downloadAppIconsInDirectory];
}
}

// code for download image

-(void)downloadAppIconsInDirectory
{
NSURL *downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_applicationObject.iconURL];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];

__weak  ApplicationCell* weakSelf = self;

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithURL:downloadURL completionHandler:^(NSURL *location,  NSURLResponse *respone, NSError *error)
          {
              NSString *iconName = [location lastPathComponent];
              NSMutableString *changeIconName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

              changeIconName = [iconName mutableCopy];

              [changeIconName setString:_applicationObject.bundleId];![enter image description here][1]

              NSString *appIconDirectory = [[documentsDirectoryForAppIcons absoluteString] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"appIcons"];

              destinationUrlForAppIcons = [[NSURL URLWithString:appIconDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:changeIconName];

              NSError *error1;

              BOOL status = [appIconFileManager copyItemAtURL:location toURL:destinationUrlForAppIcons error:&error1];
              if (status && !error1)
                  {
                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      [weakSelf refreshViews];
                      });

                      [appDelgate.saveAppIconURLAndPathInFile setValue:destinationUrlForAppIcons.path forKey:_applicationObject.iconURL];

                      NSString *dictSavedFilePath = [appDelgate.documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IconURLsAndPaths.plist"];

                      dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                      [appDelgate.saveAppIconURLAndPathInFile writeToFile:dictSavedFilePath atomically:YES];
                      });
                  }

          }];
    [downloadTask resume];
});
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code for the UITableView delegate methods, so we can see how you are trying to use the images

Answer (score 0):

As it shows, there is no error in code. This means you are priority for queues is wrong. Image must be downloaded before scrolling. As you scroll your view slow, image gets enough time to be downloaded. This means you change your code to this and try ;)

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration        
 defaultSessionConfiguration];
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:nil 
 delegateQueue:nil];
__weak  ApplicationCell* weakSelf = self;

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

 downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithURL:downloadURL completionHandler:^(NSURL *location,   

      {
          NSString *iconName = [location lastPathComponent];
          NSMutableString *changeIconName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

          changeIconName = [iconName mutableCopy];

          [changeIconName setString:_applicationObject.bundleId];![enter image description here]  
          [1]

          NSString *appIconDirectory = [[documentsDirectoryForAppIcons absoluteString] 
          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"appIcons"];

          destinationUrlForAppIcons = [[NSURL URLWithString:appIconDirectory]    
          URLByAppendingPathComponent:changeIconName];

          NSError *error1;

          BOOL status = [appIconFileManager copyItemAtURL:location    
          toURL:destinationUrlForAppIcons error:&error1];
          if (status && !error1)
              {
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  [weakSelf refreshViews];
                  });

                  [appDelgate.saveAppIconURLAndPathInFile 
  setValue:destinationUrlForAppIcons.path forKey:_applicationObject.iconURL];

                  NSString *dictSavedFilePath = [appDelgate.documentDirectoryPath 
  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IconURLsAndPaths.plist"];

                  dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                  [appDelgate.saveAppIconURLAndPathInFile writeToFile:dictSavedFilePath 
 atomically:YES];
                  });
              }

      }];
[downloadTask resume];
});
}
```

Comment: If we make call to refreshViews method before saving content in dictionary which does not solve the problem.
Is there any alternate solution to solve this problem ? 
:)

Comment: I think you must call refreshViews after saving content in dictionary, not before.

Answer (score 0):

replace your refreshViews method with this

```
    -(void)refreshViews
    {

        self.appLabelName.text = _applicationObject.name;
        self.appLabelName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17];
        self.detailTextLabel.text = _applicationObject.artistName;
        self.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];

        _appIcon.image = nil;
        NSString *appIconStoredPath = [appDelgate.saveAppIconURLAndPathInFile valueForKey:_applicationObject.iconURL];
        _appIcon.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:appIconStoredPath];

        if(!_appIcon.image && appDelgate.hasInternetConnection)
        {
            [self downloadAppIconsInDirectory];
        }
    }
```

Its load previous image because your tableview reuse the cell so the imageview also reusing which hold the previous image. so you have to do nil this image

Comment: If we make the _appIcon.image= nil ; is not working. i checked the dictionary contents different image URL (key) have same image local path (value). & if we make appIcon nil which does not affect anything. bcoz the dictionary contents wrong image local path.

Comment: To avoid this problem, I use NSURLSession delegates instead of completion block.

Refer Link : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Background_Transfer_Service_Tutorial